# MongoDB working with indexed array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

For example, I have a collection "test" with an index on array field "numbers", I have two documents there:

```
db.test.createIndex({"numbers": 1})
db.test.insert({"title": "A", "numbers": [1,4,9]})
db.test.insert({"title": "B", "numbers": [2,3,7]})
```

**1)** How can I get all results sorted by "numbers" (using index), so for each value from an array I get a full document? Like this:

```
 {"_id": "...", "title": "A", "numbers": [1,4,9]}
 {"_id": "...", "title": "B", "numbers": [2,3,7]}
 {"_id": "...", "title": "B", "numbers": [2,3,7]}
 {"_id": "...", "title": "A", "numbers": [1,4,9]}
 {"_id": "...", "title": "B", "numbers": [2,3,7]}
 {"_id": "...", "title": "A", "numbers": [1,4,9]}
```

**2)** How can I get such results (sorry for no explanation, but I think it's clear what I'm trying to achieve here):

```
 {"_id": "...", "title": "A", "numbers": 1}
 {"_id": "...", "title": "B", "numbers": 2}
 {"_id": "...", "title": "B", "numbers": 3}
 {"_id": "...", "title": "A", "numbers": 4}
 {"_id": "...", "title": "B", "numbers": 7}
 {"_id": "...", "title": "A", "numbers": 9}
```

**3)** How can I get similar results, but ordering by the second element in each array?:

```
 {"_id": "...", "title": "B", "numbers": 3}
 {"_id": "...", "title": "A", "numbers": 4}
```

Also I care about the performance, so it'd be great if you explain which technique is faster / slower (if there is more than one way to do it, of course). Thanks.

UPD: Let me clarify. We have an index on "numbers" array. So I want to iterate this index from min to max values and get a document which the current value belongs. So some document will be presented in results N times, where N = number of elements in its array ("numbers" in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the index in the sort by ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation):

```js
db.collection.find().sort({ "numbers.0": 1 })
```

Which is the fastest way if you now the position of which you want, so just use the "index" ( starting at `0` of course ). So the same applies to any indexed position of the array.

If you want the "smallest" value in an array to sort by, then that takes more work, using [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to work that out:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$numbers" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "numbers": { "$push": "$numbers" },
        "min": { "$min": "$numbers" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "min": 1 } }
])
```

And naturally that is going to take more time in execution due to the work done than the earlier form. It of course requires the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) in order to de-normalize the array elements to individual documents, and the the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with specifically [**`$min`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) to find the smallest value. Then of course there is the basic [**`$sort`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) you need.

---

For the full thing then you can basically do this:

```js
  db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
      "title": 1,
      "numbers": 1,
      "copy": "$numbers"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$copy" },
    { "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "number": "$copy"
      },
      "numbers": { "$first": "$numbers" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id.number": 1 } }
  ])
```

Which produces:

```js
{ 
  "_id" : { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("560545d64d64216d6de78edb"), 
    "number" : 1
  }, 
  "numbers" : [ 1, 4, 9 ]
}
{ 
  "_id" : { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("560545d74d64216d6de78edc"), 
    "number" : 2
  },
  "numbers" : [ 2, 3, 7 ]
}
{ 
  "_id" : { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("560545d74d64216d6de78edc"), 
    "number" : 3
  }, 
  "numbers" : [ 2, 3, 7 ]
}
{ 
  "_id" : { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("560545d64d64216d6de78edb"),
    "number" : 4
  },
  "numbers" : [ 1, 4, 9 ]
}
{ 
  "_id" : { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("560545d74d64216d6de78edc"),
    "number" : 7
  },
  "numbers" : [ 2, 3, 7 ]
}
{ 
  "_id" : { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("560545d64d64216d6de78edb"),
    "number" : 9
  },
  "numbers" : [ 1, 4, 9 ]
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, but your solution doesn't do this **for each value from an array I get a full document**. how can I get it?
UPD: I want to get 6 (six) results in the first and second cases

Comment: @d-d Of course it does. Sorting by "index" ( your question title, despite the multiple questions - and please don't do that again, first post forgiven ) does not affect the document in any way. As for the `.aggregate()` approach, when using operators like `$group` or `$project` it it up to "you" to define the fields you want to return. Operators like [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) will help you here. Read some documentation and don't make hasty comments like "does not work" to those with more knowledge than yourself when you want help.

Comment: @d-d And **for each value in an array** ( I can shout too ) then just use `$unwind` without the `$group` and sort on the value. Pretty simple if you spent more than two seconds actually reading the useful information you were just given.

Comment: I've just checked again, and your solution returns only two results, not six.

Comment: but thanks for pointing to $unwind, it seems to be what I'm looking for

Comment: @d-d Did I not just warn you about asking multiple questions in a single question. I answered "one" of them which is all you get ( in fact I actually answered two ). Learn the rules of the site please.

Comment: I'm confused.. Why can't I ask questions in comments?

Comment: @d-d This is not a chat room or a dicussion forum. It is a "Question and Answer resource" which means "one question" and hopefully "one accepted answer" and maybe several answers which is something for others with similar questions to yourself can look up and find as well. I suggest some time spend reading the site guides. But nonetheless, your complete answer is added to the answer here now, so take another look.